# Which factors dictate the mineral composition in plants\vegetables?

Tags: plant-physiology, minerals

[Here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/167942/Nutrient_analysis_of_fruit_and_vegetables_-_Summary_Report.pdf)'s a table of vegetables mineral composition (one of many), just as an example. Each vegetable contains different amounts of minerals, and my question is why is that, or in other words: **Which factors dictate the mineral composition of different vegetables**, since the diffusion process by which the minerals are absorbed from the ground into the root is essentially the same for all plants\vegetables?